# What does requirejs.config() do?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am having trouble understanding about requirejs.config() function.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../lib/require/text',
        'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
        'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
        'transitions' : '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
        'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-3.1.0',
        'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery'
       }
    }
});
```

What does the function do? Please do not direct me to the documentation because I have read it and still found it confusing. I need a simple explanation on what this function does.

Are these scripts loaded asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates aliases for script paths ant tells how to interpret bootstrap (non-AMD script) when loaded. Nothing is loaded yet. You have to require:

```
// we load two dependencies here
// `knockout` and `bootstrap` are expanded to values in config
// .js added to values
// callback function called when all dependencies are loaded
require(['knockout', 'bootstap'], function(Knockout, $) {
    // jQuery is passed to this function as a second parameter
    // as defined in shim config exports
});
```

Comment: Do you mean to say the only non-AMD script in here is bootstrap?

Comment: Not necceserily. But shim config is used to "amdify" scripts. You may safely skip it and use global instance.

Answer (score 0):

The **path** is like declarations/definitions. So for example,

```
jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
```

you can later load this lib as follows.

```
define([
  'jquery'
], function (jquery) {
   //initialize or do something with jquery
}
```

You don't have to specify the absolute path of the library.

In **shim**, you will define dependencies.  So for example,

```
paths: {
  template: '../templates',
  text:  '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
  jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
  backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
  underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
  Router: 'routes/router'
},
shim: {
  'backbone': ['underscore', 'jquery'],
  'App': ['backbone']
}
```

Here **backbone** is dependent on **underscore** and **jquery**. So those two libs will be loaded before **backbone** starts loading. Similarly **App** will be loaded after backbone is loaded.

You might find this repo useful if you are familiar with backbone and express.

https://github.com/sohel-rana/backbone-express-boilerplate

Comment: So if there is any js which depends on another js, I have to enter them in shim?

Comment: Yes, you have to define them in shim. Because the JS will load  asynchronously. But often you will have lib that depends on other lib. For example , a jquery plugin needs jquery loaded first. So you have to add jquery as dependency for that plugin.